# Finding Maclaurin series grade 4

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I've tried finding the Maclaurin series grade 4 of the function:

$cos(x^2)$

I calculated the four derivatives of the function manually and failed somewhere along the way. Is there an easier way to finding the series instead of calculating all the derivatives manually?

**EDIT: My derivatives:**

$f'(x) = -sin(x^2)*2x$

$f''(x) = -cos(x^2)*4x^2-sin(x^2)$

$f'''(x) = sin(x^2)*8x^3 - 10x*cos(x^2)$

$f''''(x) = cos(x^2)*16x^4 + sin(x^2)*24x^2 - cos(x^2) + 20x^2*sin(x^2)$

Comment: Use the expansion for $\cos(y)$ and replace $y$ by $x^2$

Comment: At first I misread the title as this being a problem on someone's fourth grade homework :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the known Maclaurin series for $\cos{x}$ and just substitute $x^2$ instead of $x$.

Comment: I found $1 - x^4/2! + x^8/4!$
is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that is correct!

Comment: Are you sure? Because my textbook says the solution is $1 - x^4/2!$ .

Comment: That is because you found the series to the term $x^8$. All you need is the first two.